# Need help to convert a curl call into VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, api, curl

I have a few commands that I am running via CURL and they get response from an API. I am converting them into VB.net.

I have this request

```
curl --location --request GET http://ip:port/
```

and I converted into vb.net like this.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        
        ' Make HTTP Request
        Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://ip:port/")
        Request.Method = "GET"
        Request.Credentials = userCredentials
        
        ' Get HTTP Response
        
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim str As String = reader.ReadLine()
        Do While str.Length >= 0
            Console.WriteLine(str)
            str = reader.ReadLine()
        Loop
        If (Console.ReadLine() = "EXIT") Then
            Environment.Exit(0) 'or, simply return from the Main method
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

The response is as expected.

Now I have an other curl command that calls a requests a Post method and downloads a file into D:\ . So it has additional parameters.

```
curl --location --request POST "http://ip:port/copy" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw "{"file":"//path/file.xlsx"}" >> D:\file.xlsx
```

I have tried this until now but I am lost on that how to pass all the parameters to make it work.

```
    Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://ip:port/copy")
    Request.Method = "POST"
    Request.ContentType = "application/json"
    Request.Credentials = userCredentials
```

how do I pass the --data-raw and D:\file.xlsx and what should I use to get response.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not tied to using HttpWebRequest, HttpClient (available from .NET Framework 4.5) is considered a better library.

The --location parameter instructs curl to follow http redirects (responsed with 3XX code), which HttpClient does automatically.

The --data-raw param sends data, as if submitted from a file control in a html form (content-type being application/x-www-form-urlencoded).

I read the info above at: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html

Using HttpClient, posting a file is simple:

```
        Dim client As New HttpClient()
        Dim content As New ByteArrayContent(IO.File.ReadAllBytes("path_to_my_file"))
        Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.PostAsync("<my url>", content)
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
```

Maybe because of the data-raw parameter, you need to use the `MultipartFormDataContent` in place of the `ByteArrayContent`.

```
Dim client As New HttpClient()
Dim b As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("<path_to_my_file>")
Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(b, 0, b.Length)
ms.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
Dim content = New MultipartFormDataContent()
content.Add(New StreamContent(ms))
Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.PostAsync("<my url>", content)
```

I hope these help.

Comment: To post a JSON request, add to the default headers `.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))` and set the HttpRequest content to a `new StringContent([The JSON string])`

Comment: That is correct, but it seems OP wants to  post a JSON request and submit an xlsx file as well?